# grep for lines containing "standard" US characters only

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to figure out how to `grep` for lines that are made up of A-Z and a-z exclusively, that is, the "American" alphabet of letters. I would expect this to work, but it does not:

```
$ echo -e "Jutland\nJastrząb" | grep -x '[A-Za-z]*'
Jutland
Jastrząb
```

I want this to only print "Jutland", because **ą** is not a letter in the American alphabet. How can I achieve this?

Comment: am not able to replicate your sample command on Ubuntu, so there may be other things at play, like locale settings.. also, use `grep -xE '[A-Za-z]+'` to avoid matching empty line

Comment: My locale is `en_US.UTF-8` so I'm leaning more towards the version of grep or something (3.3)

Comment: By far the most likely answer is that that is NOT your locale. Try setting it explicitly on the command line with `echo -e "Jutland\nJastrząb" | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 grep -x '[A-Za-z]\+'` and let us know the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use perl regex:

```
$ echo -e "Jutland\nJastrząb" | grep -P '^[[:ascii:]]+$'
Jutland
```

It's experimental though:

```
-P, --perl-regexp
      Interpret  the  pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE).  This is experimental and
      grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```

EDIT

For letters only, use `[A-Za-z]`:

```
$ echo -e "L'Egyptienne\nJutland\nJastrząb" | grep -P '^[A-Za-z]+$'
Jutland
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, but has an unexpected side effect: it allows apostrophes and hyphens. Do you know of a way to only check for literal letters? Example of what is waved through but shouldn't: `L'Egyptienne`

Comment: Use the same class that you mentioned in the question: `'^[A-Za-z]+$'`

Comment: I don't see how PCRE will behave differently than BRE/ERE for the regex being used.. any manual reference to indicate this will work with `-P` and not otherwise?

Comment: Just empirical tests - it works correctly with PCRE and allows `Jastrząb` for grep regex.

Comment: oh ok, seems like both you and OP are seeing that behavior.. I feel it has to do with locale and somehow `-P` works differently compared to default regex.. for reference, I don't see any difference between the two regexes, and I'm on `en_IN` locale

Comment: `$ echo $LANG ` gives me
`en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `LC_ALL=C` before `grep`:

```
printf '%b\n' "Jutland\nJastrząb" | LC_ALL=C grep -x '[A-Za-z]*'
```

```
Jutland
```

You may also use `-i` switch to ignore case and reduce regex:

```
printf '%b\n' "Jutland\nJastrząb" | LC_ALL=C grep -ix '[a-z]*'
```

`LC_ALL=C` avoids locale-dependent effects otherwise your current LOCALE treats `ą` as `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: `$ echo -e "Jutland\nJastrząb" | grep -x '[A-Za-z]\+'` this does not work.

Comment: I copy pasted your command and it doesn't work. This is on bash version 5.0.9(1) and (GNU grep) 3.3

Comment: Please run `echo -e "Jutland\nJastrząb" | LC_ALL=C grep -x '[A-Za-z]\+'`

Comment: That worked. Odd, but the other response with `-P` seems to have fixed this without the need for caring about locale. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: `-P` is **experimental** perl mode in `grep` which is only available on some `grep` versions but is not portable.

Comment: @pzkpfw if use of `-P` "fixes" the problem that means it's ignoring your locale setting and is therefore broken in which case I wouldn't trust it.